# SASS in Octopress

Tags: sass, gitignore, octopress

My sass folder can not render screen.css when I `rake generate`, I don't know why, but it happens since I updated octopress, so, everytime I deploy my blog, I have to do the following steps:

1. go to `_deploy` and do `git pull origin master`
2. go back to root folder and do `rake generate` and `rake deploy`, after that,
3. go to my github repo, and manually edit `stylesheets\screen.css` to the previous version.

So, actually I have two questions:

1. How to add .`stylesheets\screen.css` in `_deploy` folder? (I rarely change the stylesheet, though..)
2. How to fix the "sass generator" so, it can work normally again?

Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review your Rakefile and the code under `task :generate do`. It should be compiling the css file like `system "compass compile -css dir #{source_dir}/stylesheets"`